# Syntax for Passing a Callback into a GestureDetector in Flutter from a Model

Tags: flutter

I am trying to figure out how to pass an onTap callback from one class to another.

I have created a model that I use to build lists with, in that model there is an onTap property, what I would like to do is define which callback to you and then access the on tap from within a view.

**The Model which is to hold the callback**

```
class MasterListsModel{
  final ListRowType rowType;
  final String assetName;
  final String name;
  final Color textColor;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final void onTap; // <<------ The property that holds the callback
```

**The list definition example**

```
List<MasterListsModel> rows(Store<PrimeAppStateModel> store){
    List<MasterListsModel> list = [
      new MasterListsModel(
        ListRowType.headlinePrime,
        name: l10n.d1SearchHeader
      ),
      new MasterListsModel(ListRowType.icon,
        name: l10n.d1SearchMembers,
        textColor: hColors.white,
        assetName: hGraphics.segmentIconMembersWhite,
        backgroundColor: hColors.transparent,
        onTap: someVoidCallBackHere // <<----- The callback added to model
      ),
```

then I want evoke the the onTap from inside my list construction class.

```
return new Container(
      margin: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(35.0, 20.0, 0.0, 20.0),
      child: new GestureDetector(
        onTap: masterListModel.onTap, // << ----- Add callback
        child: new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the type `VoidCallback` instead of `void` to declare your callback inside your model.

You can also create your own callback type using `typedef`

```
typedef void MyCallback({String title});
```